# how to get specific product attribute list and option?

Tags: php, price, product-attribute, custom-options

How can i get specific product attribute list and price with product id ? is it possible to get product options like color , size and ... only with product id ? i want to add a php code to root of magento on host and when call it from browser it`s show me details of product .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about your question but I try to help you:

> How can i get specific product attribute list and price with product
>   id ? is it possible to get product options like color , size and ...
>   only with product id ?

```
//load product by ID
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);

//get attributes
$_product->getColour();
$_product->getSize();
```

> i want to add a php code to root of magento on host and when call it
>   from browser it`s show me details of product .

Seems you want to create a script that gives you the selected infos from above.
Your script could be something like:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

//get product id "id" from GET parameter
//set plausible_max_product_id
if($productID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>1, "max_range"=>plausible_max_product_id)))) {
   die("Product ID not allowed");
}

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);

//get attributes
echo $_product->getName();
echo $_product->getColour();
echo $_product->getSize();
```

Comment: Thank you it`s work fine , but when i try use getColour or getSize it`s return null .